# Cannot add a background image to a previous post/next post button in wordpress php

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have the following code :

```
<div class="wrap">
   <div class="next">
   <?php next_post('%', 'Next post', 'no'); ?>

   </div>

   <div class="prev">
    <?php previous_post('%', 'Previous post', 'no'); ?>
 </div>
</div>
```

and after hours of trying i am not able to add an image (small arrow image in png format) instead of "next post" and "previous post"

I tried (in the CSS) background-image: url(../img/arrow-left.png); amongst other things.

It does seem to work however when i create href tags

```
<a href="#" class="next"></a>
<a href="#" class="prev"></a>
```

but the problem is that I cannot embed `<?php next_post(); ?>` in the href can I ?

like so : " class="next">

which did not work for me..

If you need any more information, please let me know and I will provide it.

Comment: Does the HTML rendered by Wordpress have any classes or an ID assigned to the buttons?

Comment: try giving height and width to the anchor tag.

Comment: There's no reason you shouldn't be able to add an image as the bg and set the dimensions. Can you post what you tried, and what css is currently associate with those buttons by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress function `next_post` has been deprecated. Better to use the `next_post_link` function.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link

You can change the output format including the images like this :

```
<div class="wrap">
       <div class="next">
            <?php $next_dir = "<img src='" . get_bloginfo('template_directory') . "/img/arrow-right.png'/>"?>
            <?php next_post_link('%link', $next_dir . '<span>Next Post</span>', TRUE); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="prev">
            <?php $prev_dir = "<img src='" . get_bloginfo('template_directory') . "/img/arrow-left.png'/>"?>
            <?php previous_post_link('%link', '<span>Previous Post</span>' . $prev_dir, TRUE); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

## UPDATE 1

With the provided solution you have also to modify your css file to your needs. Another way to do this (which is better imo) is without changing any php code is to do something like this :

```
.next a{
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: url(/img/arrow-right.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}

.prev a{
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: url(/img/arrow-left.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

The html code rendered by wordpress is a links like `<a href="link-of-next-post" rel="next"></a>`.

You should also change the width and height to the dimensions of your images.

Comment: Will try this when I get home. Thanks for your reply, will let you know how it works out :)

Comment: Solved it! I'm not sure what the text-indent was for, didn't include it but after using the code from your update everything works perfectly :D

Cheers